# jQuery DataTable Search / Filter FAILS on column function generated value

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jQuery Datatables (latested ver. 1.10.19) jQuery ver. 3.3.1
Not getting expected results when Searching table:

if function is used to return a generated value for a column 
search Does Not produce the desired results.

```
var rowno =1;
var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco"]
];

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
       "columns": [
// ** DataTable search / filter FAIL: on column function generated value ***
       // { "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {return rowno++ ;}, "title" : "Row No."},
     { "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {return "row"+ rowno++ ;}, "title" : "Row No."},
      { "data": 0,"title": "Name"}, 
      { "data": 1,"title": "Position"}, 
      { "data": 2,"title": "Office"}
    ]
  } );

} );
```

SEE: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scriptgurus/q4cvr9a8/

Search on "row1.. " or row2.. row3..  We should get row with "row1" etc..

Comment: btw: also if using  the columns.render (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) - same fail -- no joy -  I have used this plugin in many projects over the years .. it maybe a version bug - as I dont seem to recall  this issue occurring in older versions.  Will be investigating that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something specific because what you doing is adding always + 1 on `rowno`. Normally you can do it this way. But in your case if you do `console.log(rowno++)` You'll  see it's adding it many times than you expect, this because the loop runs 5 times as far i can see so its adding totally 45 times. 
Array items (9*5) = 45, so you have the `meta` I saw it returns the `meta.row` with the row index, so you can do `return "row" + (meta.row + 1)` this does + 1 to the index number.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use function parameter with **meta.row** argument to get correct row number during Datatables initialization.

> This meta works since version 1.10.1

Link: [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) , [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

```
{ 
  "title" : "Row No.",
  "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
    return "row"+ (meta.row+1);
  }
},
```

**See Example below:**

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco"]
];

 $(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
       "columns": [
        { "title" : "Row No.",
          "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
            return "row"+ (meta.row+1);
          }
        },
        { "data": 0,"title": "Name"}, 
        { "data": 1,"title": "Position"}, 
        { "data": 2,"title": "Office"}
    ]
  } );
  
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks!  never looked at the meta parameter before -- Updated the jsfiddle with your fix